# What is the optimum value of parallelUploads in dropzone js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using `dropzone js` for multiple file uploading.Is there any optimum value to set for `parallelUploads` parameter.Or any convient method to find the optimal value? If its value is very small too many requests will hit on the server that will affect the server performance.(if `parallelUploads` set as 2 and if 100 files uploaded total 50 requests will hit the server right?)

Comment: I think `parallelUploads=2` means just uploading in parallel with 2 threads to reduce I/O wait.  Total requests is still 100.

Answer (score 0):

> (if parallelUploads set as 2 and if 100 files uploaded total 50 requests will hit the server right?)

Yes, this is true. If you have the option `autoProcessQueue` set to true then the queue is immediately processed, after a file is dropped or an upload finished, by calling `.processQueue()` which checks how many files are currently uploading, and if it’s less than options.parallelUploads, `.processFile(file)` is called. See http://www.dropzonejs.com/#enqueuing-file-uploads

I think there's no such thing as an optimal value. You determine the maximum uploads according to your use case. I would approach it like this, let's say you want to add multiple attachments to a certain message. In this case you have a 1 to many relationship. 'Many' is vague, define a maximum amount of attachments, I've chosen 10. In this case the value of `parallelUploads` as 2 will be enough.